# How to disable cache for a image carousel in TYPO3

Tags: caching, typo3, typoscript, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

My TYPO3 extension has a lib that generates random 5 images from the total stock, for example out of the 100 images. This is done randomly every time the page is loaded. Only default the TYPO3 cache is enabled so every time the same 5 images are showed. As the lib is in the header of the website (so on every page) I don't want to disable the cache. How can I disable the cache of only this one lib?

TypoScript:

```
plugin.tx_ExtName.widgets {
  Slider = USER
  Slider {
    userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    vendorName = Name
    extensionName = ExtName
    pluginName = Backend
    controller = Customers
    action = Slider
    switchableControllerActions {
      Customers{
        1 = Slider
      }
    }
    settings =< plugin.tx_ExtName.settings
    persistence =< plugin.tx_ExtName.persistence
    view =< plugin.tx_ExtName.view
  }
}

lib {
    slider < plugin.tx_ExtName.widgets.Slider
}
```

Comment: Which version of TYPO3 exactly it is ?

Comment: My solution to this is to simply accept the fact that the "randomness" changes only from time to time (= at cache rebuild). As it's still randomly different on each page, no one will mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `ext_localconf.php` there, where you added your plugin make an usage of the 4-th param of `configurePlugin` method

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'Vendor.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'PluginName',
    array('Customers' => 'slider',),
    array('Customers' => 'slider',) // List non-cachable action(s)
);
```

Of course fix the `VendorName` and `PluginName` to your own. It will cause that plugin's actions won't be cached, while whole page will be kept in cache still.

**Alternative solution**

You can also use JavaScript for this, just place an JS array of paths in the source code and choose 5 random items on document load it will allow you to avoid non-cached content.

Comment: I find the "alternative solution" preferrable, as if you use nc_staticfilecache (which I find very important for TYPO3), you will only be able to cache or not cache the entire page.

Comment: But with this solution all 100 images are cached and then client side 5 random images are shown. I believe this cause a lot of extra bandwidth. Therefore the random generation on server side.

Comment: 5 of 100 - that's good they are cached ONCE on the server actually - to the client side you should send only __paths__ and then with JavaScript load only 5 items. Browser will cache downloaded images itself

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution: `plugin.tx_ExtName.widgets.Slider = USER_INT`.
This makes sure that the Slider plugin is always uncached.